# Writing code for under-resourced hardware

Tags: c#, performance

I have a program which imports a large amount of users into active directory, on a server environment highly under-resourced (Client is moving to new, more powerful servers).

When writing programs that can be memory intensive for such environments, are there any best practises? Also, do memory gates come in handy in this sort of assignment?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'memory gates'???

Answer (score 1):

Not enough information.

Modern computers do have enough memory, people are just abusing them. Design your system properly to reduce the maximum amont of data you have to keep in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

It is a good idea to use [Memory pools.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool)

Comment: Do you have any references on how to use memory pools and assign .NET objects into them?  AFAIK, .NET objects are placed in managed memory heap and custom allocators can't be provided for them...